# gridview setOnIemSelectedListener not working

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have a grid view with imageview and textview. Gridview itemSelectedListener is not working.I have tried every solution provided here i.e. making focusable and clickable true or false. If I am applying click listener in adapter then its working fine. I am not understanding what the problem is.

My code is-

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity {
    TextView txtUserName;
    public CustomSharedPreferences preferences;

    // Array of strings storing options
    String[] options = new String[] {
        "Create Group",
        "Add People",
        "Personal",
        "Sharing",
    };

 // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] images = new int[]{
        R.drawable.user_group,
        R.drawable.add_user,
        R.drawable.personal,
        R.drawable.sharing,
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.option);
        txtUserName=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
        preferences = CustomSharedPreferences.getInstance(this);
        String username= preferences.getStringValue(CustomSharedPreferences.USERNAME,"");
        txtUserName.setText(username);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,options,images));
        gridView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {
                Log.e("inisde","click grid");
                Log.e("pos",""+position);
                switch(position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Intent createGrp=new Intent(HomeScreen.this,CreateGroup.class);
                        startActivity(createGrp);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Log.e("on","nothingselected");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


        });
    }
}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;
    String [] option;
    int [] imageId;
    //private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    // Keep all Images in array
   /* public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.user_group
            R.drawable.pic_2,
            R.drawable.pic_3

    };
 */
    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c,String[] options,int[] img)
    {
        mContext = c;
        option=options;
        imageId=img;
  //      inflater = ( LayoutInflater )mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return option.length;
    }
    /*@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }*/

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return option[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        // First let's verify the convertView is not null
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            // This a new view we inflate the new layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, parent,false);
        }
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        holder.img=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.img.setClickable(false);
        holder.tv.setText(option[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
       /* convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                if(position==0)
                {
                    Intent createGrp=new Intent(mContext,GroupList.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(createGrp);
                }
                else if(position==1)
                {
                    Intent addPeople=new Intent(mContext,AddMembers.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(addPeople);
                }
                else if(position==3)
                {
                    Intent sharing=new Intent(mContext,AddMembers.class);
                    mContext.startActivity(sharing);
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "You Clicked "+option[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });*/

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

**XML files-**

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/welcome_logout"/>

 <GridView
     android:id="@+id/gridView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="2" 
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/editTextMarginTop"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
     android:clickable="true">
 </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**gridlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why not use itemclicklistener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something when user click on each item in GridView, you should use setOnItemClickListener of GridView.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         if (position == 0) {
             Intent createGrp = new Intent(HomeScreen.this,CreateGroup.class);
             startActivity(createGrp);
         }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Looks your `getView` has problem, try the modified codes:

   @Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   ```
   ViewHolder holder = null;
   // First let's verify the convertView is not null
   if (convertView == null) 
   {
       // This a new view we inflate the new layout
       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout, parent,false);

       holder = new ViewHolder();

       holder.tv=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
       holder.img=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
       holder.img.setClickable(false);
       convertView.setTag(holder);  
    }
    else
       holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag(); 

       holder.tv.setText(option[position]);
       holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

    return convertView;
   ```

   }
2. `onItemSelectedListener` is for view item selection but not click, you could not get callback `onItemSelected(...)` when click. And only:

> This callback is invoked only when the newly selected position is different from the previously selected position or if there was no selected item.

Hope this help!